# MySQL Error 1148 & 1290 : Custom Date type format dd-mm-yyyy by importing csv file in MySql Workbench 8

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-workbench, import-csv

I tired several methods to import the csv file with dd-mm-yyyy date data type. First I used LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE method:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Log1.txt' 
INTO TABLE Log_tmp 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(uid, DId , CName, @var1, Price, Custom) 
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%d-%m-%y');
```

then i got the error :

> Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL
>   version

then I found a solution in this [post](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91891). ie,

```
On Windows (a little bit easier):
1. Run the following statement in MySQL Workbench:
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
2. Run the following statement and make sure it shows ON:
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "local_infile";
3. SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"; //Then you'll get the default path, usually C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads
4. Put your files into the folder shown in step 3
5. LOAD DATA without the LOCAL keyword (i.e., LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_file' INTO TABLE table_name ...)
```

After using the above method, I got following error :

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: can you import to temp table then make conversion? I am just asking for the sake of simplicity :) by the way what is your mysql version?

Comment: I will try that one. But really want a actual solution. MySQL version is 8.

Comment: can you change my.cnf?

Comment: I added the following lines in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\etc\mysqlrouter.conf   :
[client]
loose-local-infile = 1
[mysqld]
local-infile = 1

secure_file_priv=''

Comment: yep, and if you restart your mysql server , It needs to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to work if you set `loose-local-infile` to 1 in `my.cnf`

```
loose-local-infile = 1
```

then restart your mysql server.

After restart you can check global variable by issueing

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

you can also enable  local_infile without altering my.cnf  with `SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;` however please keep in mind that this variable will rollback to its original state (which is defined in my.cnf) after restart